# Unity low level network API

Tags: unity-networking, unet

I was trying out Unity Network LLAPI, I am following the [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html) tutorial. I wrote everything the same, my `server` starts well and good with no errors.

When my `client` tries to add host

`int hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topology, port);`

like this, it crashes with this error

`Cannot open socket on ip {*} and port {12000}; check please your network, most probably port has been already occupied
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkTransport:AddHost(HostTopology, Int32, String)
Client:Connect() (at path/to/game/files/Client.cs:35)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()`

Now if I change port on `client` side it says `Wrong IP or Port`.

I tried looking but didn't find much. Don't know what is wrong. Also I'm on `Linux`

Comment: "Creating a host" means you open a server for others to connect to. You do that on the server, not on the client. When your network concept makes your game participants hybrids which both create and accept connections to other participants, they are usually referred to as "peers".

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is that you didn't stop **previous host** and trying the adding new. With the same credential you are trying to add same server. So first stop host then, add host.